How to fix Variable "file_size_kb" will not stay shared at ...? Using Perl Language
The problem appears at the print line. Kindly help because I'm new to programming. My problems are variable will not stay shared in subroutine statement and unknown regexp modifier "/v" and "/e" at the #Path to the PDF file line.
# Path to the PDF file
my $pdf_file = 'path/to/your/file.pdf';

# Size threshold in kilobytes
my $size_threshold_kb = 1_000_000;

# Get the file size in bytes
my $file_size_bytes = -s $pdf_file;

# Convert bytes to kilobytes
my $file_size_kb = $file_size_bytes / 1024;

# Check if the file size is less than the threshold
if ($file_size_kb < $size_threshold_kb) {
    # Perform PDF impression reconciliation
    reconcile_pdf_impression($pdf_file);
} else {
    # Log that no reconciliation happened
    log_no_reconciliation($pdf_file);
}

sub reconcile_pdf_impression {
    my ($file) = @_;
    # Replace with actual reconciliation logic
    print "Performing PDF impression reconciliation for $file.\n";
}

sub log_no_reconciliation {
    my ($file) = @_;
    open my $log_fh, '>>', 'reconciliation.log' or die "Could not open log file: $!";
    print $log_fh "No reconciliation performed for $file because its size is $file_size_kb KB.\n";
    close $log_fh;
}

I was trying to print the file size in putting a condition in pdfs that if the size is below 1,000,000 then it will do an impression reconciliation and creates log if no impression recon.

Please don't spam random tags.

The code you posted does not exhibit any of the behaviors you describe. It simply prints "Performing PDF impression reconciliation for path/to/your/file.pdf."

Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

The "Variable foo will not stay shared" warning comes from nested named subs, which your code doesn't have. There's also no regular expressions to raise the other warning you mentioned. We can't help if the code you show isn't representative of the code giving you problems...

That happens when you have this pattern
sub {             # A sub (named or not)
   my $x;         # that contains both a lexical var
   sub named {    # and a named sub
      say $x;     # that uses the lexical var
   }
}

Here's a demo of the problem:
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub outer {
   my $x = shift;

   sub inner {
      say $x;
   }

   inner();
}

outer( 123 );
outer( 456 );

Variable "$x" will not stay shared at -e line 9.
123
123

In general, you want to avoid placing named subs in other subs.
That said, you didn't show that being done, so I suspect the script is being automatically wrapped in a sub { } so it can be called multiple times (e.g. by something like ModPerl::Registry). If so, a workaround is to use package variables.
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub outer {
   local our $x = shift;

   sub inner {
      say $x;
   }

   inner();
}

outer( 123 );
outer( 456 );

123
456

A better solution is to convert the script into a module, and reduce the script to
use MyModule qw( );
MyModule::run();

This would require more work.
In your case, the following avoids the problem.
sub reconcile_pdf_impression {
    my ($pdf_file) = @_;
    # ...
}

sub log {
    my ($msg) = @_;
    chomp $msg;
    $msg .= "\n";
    my $qfn = 'reconciliation.log';
    open my $log_fh, '>>', $qfn
       or warn("Could not open log file `$qfn`: $!\n"), return;
    print $log_fh $msg
       or warn("Could not write to log file `$qfn`: $!\n"), return;
    close $log_fh
       or warn("Could not write to log file `$qfn`: $!\n"), return;
}

sub run {
    my $pdf_file = 'path/to/your/file.pdf';
    my $size_threshold_kb = 1_000_000;
    my $file_size_bytes = -s $pdf_file;
    my $file_size_kb = $file_size_bytes / 1024;
    
    if ($file_size_kb >= $size_threshold_kb) {
        log("No reconciliation performed for $pdf_file because its size is $file_size_kb KB.");
        return;
    }

    reconcile_pdf_impression($pdf_file);
}

run();

